# using tanstack/react-query in async function

Tags: reactjs, react-query

[Condition]

I'm using click event to trigger this "handleDeleteQAPairBatch",

```js
    async function handleDeleteQAPairBatch() {
        if (selectedPairList.length < 1) return toast.error("請先選擇問答內容");
        const batchPack = selectedPairList.map((item) => ({
          op: "delete",
          value: item,
        }));
        const { result: deleteBatchResult, data } =
          await UpdateQuestionAnsweringPair(batchPack);
        const urlArray = data.split("/");
        const params = urlArray[urlArray.length - 1];
        const jobId = params.split("?")[0];
        try {
          const jobStatus = await queryClient.fetchQuery({
            queryKey: ["jobStatus"],
            queryFn: () => GetQAUpdateJobStatus(jobId),
            staleTime: 0,
          });
          console.log(jobStatus);
          setJobStatusData(jobStatus);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    
        if (deleteBatchResult) {
          toast.success("問答內容刪除成功");
          setSelectedPairList([]);
        }
      }
```

1.inside this function executes an async function "UpdateQuestionAnsweringPair" request API to update data

2.and It returns the value "data", an url contains a param "jobId"

3.using this "jobId" as param with async function GetQAUpdateJobStatus request API will get a data returned with structure like this, which indicates the update job status

```js
    {
        "createdDateTime":"2024-03-04T06:19:29+00:00",
        "expirationDateTime":"2024-03-04T12:19:29+00:00",
        "jobId":"8012fc66-0855-4ef0-b692-0b31263e59bf",
        "lastUpdatedDateTime":"2024-03-04T06:19:29+00:00",
        "status":"notStarted",
        "resultUrl":null
    }
```

when the update job is done, job status will be updated

```js
    {
        "createdDateTime": "2024-03-04T06:19:29+00:00",
        "expirationDateTime": "2024-03-04T12:19:29+00:00",
        "jobId": "8012fc66-0855-4ef0-b692-0b31263e59bf",
        "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2024-03-04T06:19:35+00:00",
        "status": "succeeded",
        "resultUrl": "/knowledgebases/MiniTai"
    }
```

[Question]
I need a way to monitor data from GetQAUpdateJobStatus API to check if property "status" changes,
and use this status to set logic to and update template

[Problem Encounter]
useQuery cant not be used inside an async function
so I use `queryClient.fetchQuery` instead,
but it only execute once, so i could not keep the status in sync with api to get the updated value,
how should I modify it, or using any alternative way with React Query?

so I use `queryClient.fetchQuery` instead,
but it only execute once, so i could not keep the status in sync with api to get the updated value,
how should I modify it, or using any alternative way with React Query?

[Alternative]
This is my alternative way,
but I found it a little bit circling(not straightforward),
is there any other method in

```
const { data: JobStatus } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["JobStatus"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      if (currentJobID) {
        try {
          const result = await GetQAUpdateJobStatus(currentJobID);
          if (result.status === "succeeded") {
            setCurrentJobID(null);
            queryClient.refetchQueries({ queryKey: ["QAPairList"] });
          }
          return result;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
    refetchInterval: 1 * 1000,
    refetchIntervalInBackground: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the query in to a proper `useQuery` hook, add a state for `jobId` that is set by `handleDeleteQAPairBatch` and have the `useQuery` hook listen to this parameter and get data once it is set.

Something like this

```js
    async function handleDeleteQAPairBatch() {
        if (selectedPairList.length < 1) return toast.error("請先選擇問答內容");
        const batchPack = selectedPairList.map((item) => ({
          op: "delete",
          value: item,
        }));
        const { result: deleteBatchResult, data } =
          await UpdateQuestionAnsweringPair(batchPack);
        const urlArray = data.split("/");
        const params = urlArray[urlArray.length - 1];
        const jobId = params.split("?")[0];

        // use states for this
        setDeleteBatchResult(deleteBatchResult);
        setJobId(jobId)
    }

/// custom hook to monitor

    function useMonitorJobStatus(jobId) {
        return useQuery({
            queryKey: ["jobStatus"],
            queryFn: () => GetQAUpdateJobStatus(jobId),
            staleTime: 0,
            // only run this query when jobId is set
            enabled: jobId !== undefined,
            // refetch every second
            refetchInterval: 1000
        }
    }

/// in component

function Component() {
    const [deleteBatchResult, setDeleteBatchResult] = useState();
    const [jobId, setJobId] = useState();

    const { data, jobStatus } = useMonitorJobStatus(jobId);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (jobStatus.status === "succeeded") {
            // do something, e.g. set logic and update template
        }
    }, [jobStatus.status]);

}
```